# Radio Button Image using Jquery 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have styled radio buttons with jQuery, and I want to make every radio button its own unique image and clicked image. But right now im using just two images for them universally.

The code can be viewed at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dGWJp/27/).

Right now i just have

```
var checkedImgUrl = 'http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/879/87952_300.jpg',
    uncheckedImgUrl = 'http://www.mediabistro.com/alltwitter/files/2011/03/twitter_block.gif';
```

How can I make each one of those images have their own unique image and clicked image?

Comment: what do you mean by unique image

Comment: Each radio has its own image, right now they all share one image.

Comment: @soniccool - Of course they share the same image. What are you expecting?

Comment: Yeah but i want to find a way to do it so they each have their own, but im not sure how to apply that. Someone helped me make this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this, is to add an attribute to your radiobutton which holds the image url, e.g.:

```
<input name="version" type="radio" value="ATT" data-imageurl="radioimage1" />
```

then in your jquery code, you can reference the imageurl like this:

```
uncheckedImgUrl = $(this).attr("data-imageurl") + '.jpg';
```

If you're hosting the images yourself, you can save the 'selected' version of the file have like '-on' at the end of it. Like so:

```
checkedImgUrl = uncheckedImgUrl + '-on.jpg';
```

Hope this helps

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/dGWJp/30/

I just made a small change to the jsfiddle because i'm too lazy to create images for an example. This jsfiddle only changes the 'checked' image to the custom one. You should have enough info now to expand on this to complete your query. This is the only code change i did inside swapImage function:

```
checkedImgUrl = $(radio).attr("data-imageurl");
```

Comment: Do you think you could maybe integrate it into that jsfiddle to show me an example?

Comment: Question though, do i need to leave the     `var checkedImgUrl = 'http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/879/87952_300.jpg';` since thats not the hover image i will be using anymore? Or can i remove it or remove the link

Comment: Also would it be the same way to go about having different unselected images?

Comment: for unselected images, refer to my answer of having the selected/unselected images having a standard suffix shared by all so you can modify the 'data-imageurl' in the code easily.